# How to pass an object from cell to new controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

For each cell in my `UITableView` I setup a custom object. Like this:

```
// Reference to the turn
PFObject *turnToPlay = [self.currentUserTurnsToPlay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

When a cell is selected I need to pass that object to a new view controller.

This is from my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"takeGameTurn" sender:self];  
}
```

I am struggling to find out how I can reference to my PFObject created for the cell, to pass it to the destination view controller. I understand I would pass this into `prepareForSegue` but how do I get my object from the cell selection.

I have reference to the indexPath from the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but how do I pass that into the segue destination controller? It is like I need another param in that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your prepareForSegue

```
  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
         if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"takeGameTurn"]){
               NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
               PFObject *turnToPlay = [self.currentUserTurnsToPlay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

          }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, needed indexPathForSelectedRow, didn't know that was available.

Answer (score 0):

Is your PFObject attribute of your cell? If yes then, you could youse

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"takeGameTurn"])
    {
        YourNextViewController *nextVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath;
        indexPath = [myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        nextVC.myPFObject = cell.assignedPfObject;


    }
}
```